# PayPal 'Pay Now' Button in Javascript without a Backend?

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

In another question I found the following has been deprecated. Specifically, `actions.order.create` and `actions.order.capture` have been deprecated and should not be used in any new integrations

So what do we use in May 2023 to avoid the backend?

My DocType at the top of the Html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I have the code in the `<header>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

In the `<body>`.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP"></script>
<div id="paypal-button-10"></div>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            layout: 'vertical', /* 'horizontal', */
            color:  'gold',
            shape:  'pill',
            label:  'buynow'
        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: "GBP",
                            value: "10.00"
                        }
                    }
                 ]
             });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Congratulations! payment success');
                console.log(details);
                console.log(details.id);  // order id
                console.log(details.status);  // 'COMPLETED'
                // send ajax request to update the db
            });
        },
        onCancel: function (data) {
            alert('Payment cancelled');
        },
        onError: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-10');
</script>
```

Comment: Please say why it is not a good question rather than just voting it down.

Comment: I came across the same issue today. For some reason a createOrder button needs a backend and a lot of logistics, while createSubscription doesn't need any backend. I'm considering using a createSubscription button with a # cycle limit to 1, effectively charging the person 1 time, and needing no backend. Did a proof of concept so far and maybe it'll be workable.

Comment: And one can use "custom_id" along with the plan_id to pass a reference number

Answer (score 3):

> How do you code a Paypal 'Pay Now' Button in Javascript without a Backend in May 2023?

All such integrations were deprecated by PayPal, so there is no supported way to do so. Alternatives are:

1. Integrate with a backend you create.
2. Install/use a pre-integrated solution, such as just about any shopping cart software or similar, that has its own backend that integrates with PayPal.

There is no option to integrate regular "Pay Now" / "Buy Now" one-time PayPal payments *without* a backend. Any of the old ways you may find to do so (including actions.order.create / actions.order.capture with the JS SDK, or HTML-only redirects/buttons) are no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this. But, surely somewhere it must say the new `create-paypal-order` and `capture-paypal-order` files, 1. Accept these arguments by post, 2. This is how you connect to Paypal, 3. This is the information sent, 4. This is the the info you need to echo, potentially in a json format. There must be some basic tutorial somewhere. I do not want to add it to a database or anything. Just the basics. There must be loads of people like me who were creating their old buttons in the wizard with no backend knowledge whatsoever.

Comment: There documentation has an example implementation of the create and capture routes in node.js .  It's just an example, you can use any other language/environment to implement the same backend routes.